# Graceful javascript re-adjustment after setting style.display= none

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make some code that deletes an item that is represented in a card on a web page.

When the user clicks the remove-item-btn ajax is called which removes the item in the backend. And on the front end the item's display is changed to none so it disappears. All of this is working well. In an instant the item disappears from the grid and the later item's have filled in its place.

**Question:** Is it possible to write javascript that causes the other cards to gracefully move over to fill in the empty space?

I am using bootstrap, sass, ruby on rails, and htmlslim.

The cards are currently in a grid that varies in width depending on the screen size with the average width of the grid being 3 cards.

HTML

```
<div class="item-card" id="2">...</div>
<div class="item-card" id="3">...</div>
<div class="item-card" id="4">...</div>
<div class="item-card" id="5">...</div>
<div class="item-card" id="6">...</div>
<div class="item-card" id="7">...</div>
```

JS

```
$('.remove-item-btn').mousedown(function(ev) {
  var item_card = document.getElementById(...);
  item_card.style.display = 'none'
  $.ajax(this removes the item)
});
```

CSS

```
.item-card {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Any time you hide an element, the rest of the page will adjust appropriately. So if this isn't happening in your case, the problem is probably due to how you've set up the rest of your page. Can you provide that?

Comment: And because you're already using jquery, it'll also be easier if you just did $("#ID_OF_ELEMENT").hide();

Comment: It is adjusting appropriately, it is just doing so in an instant, and it is not graceful. Is there a way to slow it down / animate the other cards to slide over to fill the empty space? @Sarhanis

Comment: Cheers for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just making display equal to none, you can use animation methods for hiding with jQuery. Something like this:

```
$("#ID_OF_ELEMENT").hide("slow");
```

More stuff is here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

More general animation stuff is here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/